# JBoss suddenly throwing errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

I am using Intellij and everything was working fine in. All I did was add in a new Java class file to my project and suddenly my JBoss is throwing errors. Deleting that class file makes no difference (I would be surprised if it did).

The error is as follow:

```
Error Running JBoss Server
Exception occurred: IllegalArgumentException.
Message: port our of range: 21747... (Integer max number)
```

I did not make any changes to my standalone.xml file. Checked it for any malform just in case and the xml file is valid.

I'm very confused as to what Intellij did to cause this error. If anyone faced a similar issue please advice.

Past similar issues mentioned here pretty much suggests malformed standalone file and thats not the case here.

Please refer to following image. Is that normal? I don't recall if this server settings under 'Edit Configurations' used to be empty or filled (username, password, port). If it is supposed to be filled, I don't get how it magically disappeared. I don't even recall those credentials.

[image]

Comment: Is it full error message? It claims that "21747" port is out of range?

Comment: @y.bedrov full error is jus a long number 217..., thus I truncated it mentioned in brackets that it is max integer number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue seems to have something to do with deployment stuck in memory. I had to restart my machine to clear it which I was trying to avoid.

There was no change in my standalone.xml file thus the issue is not there from what I see.

Not the best of solutions I suppose but a working solution non the less.